# Proving existence of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ square matrix which is not invertible. Prove that there exists a square matrix $B$ with at least $n$ non-zero entries such that $AB=0$.

Actually I tried to approach this by using the definition of the  matrix multiplication. But I couldn't overcome what should be the entries of $A$ in this case.
 Any help or any tricks would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ not invertible implies that its kernel has positive dimension. So let $0 \ne x \in Ker(A)$. Now, put $B = [x \ ... \ x]$, i.e., the columns of $B$ are copies of $x$.

It is easy to verify that $AB=0$ and by definition, it has at least $n$ non-zeros entries.

Comment: Great Solution !

Comment: How do we find using systems of linear equation logic? Because this exercise given by after these topics. We haven't seen the kernel yet.

Comment: Oh ok, well the kernel is the set of elements $x$ such that $Ax=0$. So to find one such element, you just need to solve the system of $n$ linear equations $Ax=0$.